# Docker breaks autofs directory in V1.5, used to work in V1.3.3

Tags: docker

Today I tried to install and start Docker 1.5. It works at the beginning. Then after about 1 hour, I cannot access autofs directories on the host any more. Get error "Too many levels of symbolic links.". And I cannot do unlink and relink autofs directories for some reason. So no way out now.

$ cd /usr/local/packages/
/usr/local/packages/: Too many levels of symbolic links.

Anyone get similar issue?

And I used Docker version 1.3.3 for several months. It works perfectly. So any change after 1.3.3 may causing this issue?

BTW, I cannot find a older version Docker rpm. If you have one, please let me know. Thanks.